# To enhance my android automation skills which apps will provide different types of element to practice?

Tags: appium, mobile-automation, android-automation

To enhance my android automation skills which apps will provide different types of element to practice with Appium test automation?
Most of the apps I download, need google authentication or OTP validation.
And looking for simple UI too.

Answer (score 2):

- Just to practice you can start with basic and default application like calculator
- If you are done with basic stuff and want to interact with diff types of elements then you can consume Amazon/Facebook android apps